# TableView cellForRowAt iterates through all cells right after calling reloadData()

Tags: swift, pagination, tableview, swift4

I used tableView alot and I know it well. but this time it works weird.

I added this delegations to the class:

```
UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource.
```

I connected the delegates from storyBoard.

cells showing currectly and everything is working fine but I wanted to add the pagination to my table and found out this methods are iterating through all the cells right after I called "tableView.reloadData()"

- cellForRowAt indexPath
- didEndDisplaying cell
- willDisplay cell

They are not wait for user to scroll the table !

What should I check!?

Comment: When you reload the data don't you expect it will have to call `cellForRowAt` so that the cells can be refreshed?

Comment: Yes but I have 3 visible cells in my tableView(height of each cell is 1/3 of view height) and "cellForRowAt"  should iterate through this 3 cells, but it iterates throuth all 10 cells!